How to rename a JPEG nested in a layer in AGOL Map Viewer
I have a georeferenced JPEG of a DWG in AGOL Map Viewer. I need to rename the .jpg to match the feature layer name:

However, when click on the .jpg's information tab in the Properties layer to go change the name,  I am taken to a JSON web page that requires a login (username and password).

When I login I get this website:

When I click on the .jpg it takes me to another website:

I own the feature layer, but ownership was transferred to me from someone else.
How can I change the name of the .jpg to match the feature layer name?

What all options do you see for this item on item details page?

It takes me to the Services Directory and it wants a User Name and Password.

do you get an option to download the jpg from your contents tab?

No, I don't get that option. It asks me to login. Sometimes my login works other times it doesn't, but when I log in I get taken to two different websites (see above), the folder then to Services Directory. Form there I can only choose JSON at the top.

When I select the JSON link, I am taken to a website with clickable headers "JSON, Raw Data, Headers". It looks like a lot of code. Don't know what to do with it.
